# Azure SDK 2.0 installation on VS 2012

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I have tried to install the Windows Azure SDK 2.0 on the VS 2012 ultimate. I have both the VS 2010 and VS 2012 on Widows 7 machine . i am getting below error

Web plat form log

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8FF1.tmp' to: C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale\5ABBB9F724A085D924844401579BC11AD8E16D73\WindowsAzureTools.vs110.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/4/9/F49D8CF8-BCDB-4F3A-8B8A-8D00077D7DF2/WindowsAzureTools.LightSwitch.vs110.exe' to: C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDD28.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Emulator - 2.0' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Emulator - 2.0' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Emulator - 2.0 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Emulator 2.0'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C echo noop'. Process Id: 6984
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Emulator 2.0' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Emulator 2.0' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Emulator 2.0 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 4
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure SDK - 2.0'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C echo noop'. Process Id: 9804
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure SDK - 2.0' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure SDK - 2.0' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure SDK - 2.0 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 5
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale\5ABBB9F724A085D924844401579BC11AD8E16D73\WindowsAzureTools.vs110.exe RUNDEVENVSETUP=0 /quiet /norestart /log C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale_Install.txt RUNDEVENVSETUP=0'. Process Id: 4928
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '844840'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '844840'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpDD28.tmp' to: C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\LightSwitch11_AzurePublish_3_0_2_0_Only_BaseLocale\5ED45E0AAE24DF8F1ACA5CE76A032B24A59EFA69\WindowsAzureTools.LightSwitch.vs110.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/4/9/F49D8CF8-BCDB-4F3A-8B8A-8D00077D7DF2/WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe' to: C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF328.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012' is '1603'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Command failed. Retries left: 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale\5ABBB9F724A085D924844401579BC11AD8E16D73\WindowsAzureTools.vs110.exe RUNDEVENVSETUP=0 /quiet /norestart /log C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale_Install.txt RUNDEVENVSETUP=0'. Process Id: 8504
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012' is '1603'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Command failed. Retries left: 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale\5ABBB9F724A085D924844401579BC11AD8E16D73\WindowsAzureTools.vs110.exe RUNDEVENVSETUP=0 /quiet /norestart /log C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale_Install.txt RUNDEVENVSETUP=0'. Process Id: 8644
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '13038504'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '13038504'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpF328.tmp' to: C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsVS2010_Only_2_0_BaseLocale\276785D5E9249D4D95F919C14326E90791FED28A\WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012' is '1603'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Command failed. Retries left: 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsOnlyVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale\5ABBB9F724A085D924844401579BC11AD8E16D73\WindowsAzureTools.vs110.exe RUNDEVENVSETUP=0 /quiet /norestart /log C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsVS2012_2_0_BaseLocale_Install.txt RUNDEVENVSETUP=0'. Process Id: 8656
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012' is '1603'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 6
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'LightSwitch Azure Publishing 3.0 add-on for Visual Studio 2012'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'LightSwitch Azure Publishing 3.0 add-on for Visual Studio 2012'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2012) - 2.0'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 7
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product LightSwitch Azure Publishing 3.0 add-on for Visual Studio 2012 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 8
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product LightSwitch Azure Publishing 3.0 add-on for Visual Studio 2012 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 9
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2012) - 2.0 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 10
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsVS2010_Only_2_0_BaseLocale\276785D5E9249D4D95F919C14326E90791FED28A\WindowsAzureTools.VS100.exe /quiet /norestart /log C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsAzureToolsVS2010_Only_2_0_BaseLocale_Install.txt'. Process Id: 1168
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 11
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Language Packs'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C echo noop'. Process Id: 9476
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Language Packs' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Language Packs' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Language Packs done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 12
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C echo noop'. Process Id: 8580
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 13
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C echo noop'. Process Id: 8968
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools 2.0 for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 14
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2010 SP1) - 2.0'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C echo noop'. Process Id: 1184
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2010 SP1) - 2.0' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2010 SP1) - 2.0' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2010 SP1) - 2.0 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 15
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Executing post install commands for product: Visual Studio 2012 Setup Helper
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Visual Studio 2012 Setup Helper'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\Dev11DevenvSetupHelper\840104A2546080B219D56900C44E75F786239BB9\Preparation.exe -l C:\Users\gowdes\AppData\Local\Temp\Dev11DevenvSetupHelper_Install.log'. Process Id: 4652
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Visual Studio 2012 Setup Helper' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Visual Studio 2012 Setup Helper' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Visual Studio 2012 Setup Helper done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 16
```

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: LightSwitch Azure Publishing 3.0 add-on for visual studio 2012. This product can be installed  because a product that it depends on did not install successfully

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use Windows Web Platform installer to install the Lightswitch add-on. The installer will find all the dependencies and ensure that you have everything needed to make the add-on run.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Search for "Lightswitch" after the installer has finished and you will see the add-on.

Comment: Hi newtonrd,i am still getting the same error ... after adding the lightwsitch ..